# Failed building wheel for Pillow. Could not build wheels for Pillow?

Tags: python, deep-learning, python-imaging-library

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/cy/jb4hhgz14g7g2cphkbnc41640000gn/T/pip-install-15nfkpqs/pillow_7491cec5f94142c5891534157b14f6f2/setup.py", line 918, in <module>
          raise RequiredDependencyException(msg)
      __main__.RequiredDependencyException:
      
      The headers or library files could not be found for zlib,
      a required dependency when compiling Pillow from source.
      
      Please see the install instructions at:
         https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html
      
      
      [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
Running setup.py clean for Pillow
Failed to build Pillow
ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I'm trying to execute a project and this is
github link: https://github.com/navassherif98/Recipe-Generation-from-Food-Image

I tried asking ChatGPT it gave some commands but this error is still coming can anyone know how to fix this please

Comment: Install and/or update the zlib library (depends on the OS you are using)

Comment: The error message has a link to the install instructions. Did you follow that link? And did you install everything for zlib?

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to be building Pillow from source. From the paths I'd guess you're on macOS, but which version of it, which Python, etc.?